# Node.js mongodb driver, sockets closed error

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Upon trying to connect to a mongodb database using the official driver, I get the error:

```
{ [MongoError: server database_address sockets closed]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'database_address sockets closed' }
```

Looking online, I tried to call the connect function like this:

```
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var url = 'database_address';

var dbOptions = {
    server: {
        'auto_reconnect': true,
        'poolSize': 20,
        socketOptions: {
            'keepAlive': 1,
            'connectTimeoutMS': 30000
        }
    },
    replset: {
        socketOptions: {
            'keepAlive': 1,
            'connectTimeoutMS': 30000
        }
    }
};

...

MongoClient.connect(url, dbOptions, function(err, db) {...})
```

But the error remains.

Is there another way? Thanks.

Comment: Do you use the latest driver version? Had the same issue – lib update solved it.

Comment: 2.0.42, which should be the latest version.

Comment: `var url = 'database_address';` is this correct? Shouldn't url have host and port along with database name.

Comment: Placeholder name, connects fine to the real url.Just don't want to post my database url complete with username and password :P.